# c# equivalent to java.util.concurrent.Future<T>

Tags: c#, java, equivalent

What is the closest equivalent to Java's `Future<T>` in C#?

For example, what would the closest reconstruction of the following be in C#:

```
public class FutureMethodCall implements Future {
    private Future<APIResponse> methodCall;

    public boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) {
        return this.methodCall.cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning);
    }

    public APIResponse get() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        return this.methodCall.get();
    }

    ...
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can google for Task<TResult>

Comment: If you can't use Task (because you are stuck in an older version of C#) try my promises implementation: https://github.com/Real-Serious-Games/C-Sharp-Promise. Also available on nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/RSG.Promise/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what a Future does in Java, but from the code it looks like you are executing code at a later time that runs asyncronously and is cancelable.

Have a look at [Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dd321424%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in C#, they offer the same capabilities.